# Filtering a data frame with multiple column values of another data frame

Tags: python, pandas, loops, filtering

I have 2 data frames as below:

```
df1={"group":["A","B"],
 "unit":["U1","U2"],
 "char1":["C1","C2"],
 "char2":["Large","Medium"],
 "char3":["","R"]
}
df1=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df1)
```

and

```
df2={"char1":["C1","C1","C1","C1","C2","C2","C2","C3","C3"],
"char2":["Large","Large","Large","Large","Medium","Medium","Medium","Medium","Large"],
 "char3":["U","U","U","R","R","R","U","R","R"],
 "result":[113,114,115,116,818,819,1101,1102,1103]}

df2=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df2)
```

I want to filter df2 with the values of df1 columns(char1,char2,char3).
Finally, for each group_unit pair in df1, I want to assign filtered results from df2.

The desired output would look like the following:

```
output={"group":["A","A","A","A","B","B"],
    "unit" :["U1","U1","U1","U1","U2","U2"],
    "result":[113,114,115,116,818,819]}
output=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(output)
```

I have tried using "isin" and some other stuff but couldn't manage to get there.
I appreciate with any kind of soft coding solution.

Comment: your output is not correct if you want to "filter" on char1 char2 and char3

Comment: @Chris, you're right. I corrected the example output. Thanks for the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this task with a **single** instruction:

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['char1', 'char2'])[['group', 'unit', 'result']]
```

`merge` (not surprisingly) merges `df1` and `df2`, but the result contains
also `char1`, `char2`, `char3_x` and `char3_y` columns,
so you need to "restrict" the output to the columns you want.

Note that the result column list is in **double** square brackets
(you may say: a weird notation).

The reason is that:

- "outer" pair is a "normal" pair for an index,
- but because instead of a single column name we have a **list** of
  column names, it must be enclosed with another pair of square brackets.

And a little remark concerning your expected output:

The last "your" row (B, U2, 1102) should not actually be included.
Note that the last but one row in `df2` (C3, Medium, R, 1102) contains
`C3` as `char1` and `Medium` as `char2`, but `df1` does not contain
any row containing these values.

## Edit

You wrote that you want to filter (actually merge) on **all three** *char1*,
*char2* and *char3* columns.

So probably:

- Dictionary for `df1` should containt `'char3':['U', 'R']` (note the added 'U').
- The `merge` instruction should be: `pd.merge(df1, df2)` (with default merge
  criterion of all common columns), the "[[...]]" part as before.

Then the result would contain:

```
  group unit  result
0     A   U1     113
1     A   U1     114
2     A   U1     115
3     B   U2     818
4     B   U2     819
5     B   U2    1101
```

i.e. three rows containing `C1`, `Large` and `U` and another three rows
containing `C2`, `Medium` and `R`.

## Edit 2

In order to perform the filtering the way you explained in your comment,
you have to split `df1` into 2 DataFrames:

- `df1a` containig an empty string in `char3`, dropping `char3` column
  (the reason is explained below),
- `df1b` containig not empty string in `char3`.

To do it run:

```
df1a = df1.query('char3.str.len() == 0').drop('char3', axis=1)
df1b = df1.query('char3.str.len() > 0')
```

Then you should concatenate two partial merges:

- `df1a` with `df`, using the default merge criterion - all common columns
  (`char1` and `char2`, so now it becomes clear why we dropped `char3`),
- `df1b` with `df`, again - on all common columns (this time `char1`, `char2`
  and `char3`),
- leaving only `group`, `unit` and `result` columns.

To do it run:

```
pd.concat([pd.merge(df1a, df2), pd.merge(df1b, df2)])[['group', 'unit', 'result']]
```

Comment: you are right regarding your remark on the desired output. I corrected, thanks. I also made an edit on the df2 to be more explicit. When it comes to your remark on df1, I created 'char3':[' ', 'R'] on purpose. Because I want the code to bring all results under "char3" if the char value is blank/null. For example, A_U1 pair should get all possible results (113,114,115,116) since there is no "char3" criteria specified for this pair. One last point: You did not use any char3 in your solution. However, B_U2 pair suggests the "R" for "char3" criteria. How you would write the code considering those?